# Dynamic create div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I was trying to use `Google Chart pie` and show many Pies in the same page.
So, I need to create dynamic `div`. Btw I use `ASP.NET`

Here is my `javascript`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'printG.aspx/GetData',
            data: '{}',
            success:
                function (response) {
                    drawVisualization(response.d);
                }
        });
    })

    function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var ele = document.createElement("div");
        ele.setAttribute("style", "width: 600px;");
        ele.setAttribute("style", "visualization");
        ele.setAttribute("id", "width: 600px;");
        output.appendChild(ele);

        //data.addColumn('string', 'title');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Anstitle');
        data.addColumn('number', 'chooseP');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]  );
            console.log(dataValues[i].ColumnName +" "+ dataValues[i].Value+" "+ i);
        }

        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, { title: dataValues[0].QuestionName });


    } 

</script>
```

Html

```
<div id="output" class="out">
```

However, it show an error :

> Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

It looks like I didn't create a container where google pie appended value.

How to fix it?

Comment: There's no reference to a variable named `Container` in your code.  Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are referring to your new dynamic div using an ID of "visualization":

```
new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, { title: dataValues[0].QuestionName });
```

But you are setting the ID to `"width: 600px;"` here:

```
    ele.setAttribute("style", "width: 600px;");
    ele.setAttribute("style", "visualization");
    ele.setAttribute("id", "width: 600px;");
```

Perhaps think about those attributes and what you really want them to be set to.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the dynamic ID to the 'div' you have created. For your case, I am assigning the 'id' property for the div as 'dynamicId0'. You can change it to more meaningful value.

```
function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.prop('id', 'dynamicId0');
        ele.setAttribute("style", "width: 600px;");
        ele.setAttribute("style", "visualization");
        ele.setAttribute("id", "width: 600px;");
        output.appendChild(ele);

        //data.addColumn('string', 'title');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Anstitle');
        data.addColumn('number', 'chooseP');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]  );
            console.log(dataValues[i].ColumnName +" "+ dataValues[i].Value+" "+ i);
        }

        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('dynamicId0')).
            draw(data, { title: dataValues[0].QuestionName });   
    }
```

Here is code from my application to display pie chart using google chart. I hope it will give you an idea,

**Html**

```
<div id="piechart_container"></div>
```

**Java Script**

```
function drawPieChart(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Priority');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, parseInt(dataValues[i].Value)]);
    }

    var options = {
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        'is3D': true,
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto',
        'chartArea': { width: "100%" },
        colors: ['#dc3912', '#ff9900', '#3366cc', '#109618', '#36C9C2', '#C9C536']

    };

    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_container')).
        draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Just like you said, I found I put the wrong word `ele.setAttribute("id", "width: 600px;");`  ,I change to `visualization`and it work. But your example is also great!